# If occured said times for said condition

Tags: r

From the table below I would like to know if at least two ethiopians took part in marathon in Amsterdam.
Any tips appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput(head(mydata))` instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with some help I figured it out

```
cities_with_2_eth <- df |>
  filter(nation == "ETH") |>
  group_by(Venue) |>
  summarize(n = n()) |>
  filter(n >= 2)
cities_with_2_eth_names <- unique(cities_with_2_eth$Venue)
cities_with_2_eth_fin <- df[df2$Venue %in% cities_with_2_eth_names,]
```

Credit goes to guys from discoRd